# Rails custom configuration returns an empty hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, configuration

I'm using Rails 4, and I would like to use the custom configuration functionality as explained here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration

I created the following YAML file (`config\prefs.yml`):

```
development:
  password: test
```

And I added this to my `config/application.rb`:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...

    config.x.prefs = Rails.application.config_for(:prefs)
  end
end
```

When I go to the rails console, I get this:

```
> Rails.configuration.x.prefs
=> {}
```

Why isn't Rails correctly loading the configuration?

Comment: When you run `Rails.env` is it showing `"development"` or something else? If you're not running in development environment for some reason then when it sets the prefs hash it will be empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm guessing the following:

- You have the [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) gem bundled in.
- Your custom configuration somehow got initialized in the state it is currently in. (i.e. empty)
- The `config\prefs.yml` isn't tracked by Spring, so it doesn't know the environment needs to be reloaded.

If i'm correct, you'll just have to create an initializer with the following code:

```
Spring.watch "config/prefs.yml"
```

And, of course, you'll have to reload the console each time the config is changed. I've managed to reproduce and solve your issue with this, so i hope this helps.

Comment: `reload!` is a great way to quickly reload the console

Comment: I'm sorry for coming back to this late, I was traveling. This is exactly the reason why I was having this issue, you are completely right. I added your line to `config/spring.rb`, and everything is working properly. By the way, @blnc `reload!` command doesn't work.

Comment: @hattenn it works for updates to the model, thought it might for spring

Comment: @blnc, I used `reload!` a lot too, but it doesn't work for spring. I guess it would be convenient if it did.

Answer (score 0):

I try your code on my machine and working fine i think maybe problem with configuration you did in `config/application.rb` or you need to reload your rails console with reload command `reload!`

that my configuration for `config/application.rb`

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module WSApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Do not swallow errors in after_commit/after_rollback callbacks.
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    config.x.prefs = Rails.application.config_for(:prefs)
  end
end
```

that your file `prefs.yml`

```
development:
  password: test
```

here is the result

[image]