# Rails `config_for` returning an empty hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841718/rails-custom-configuration-returns-an-empty-hash) yet the solution did not work for me. As per the [rails docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration), I've taken the following steps:

I've created a file `config/benchmarks.yml`, with the following content:

`Test: "This"`

I also added `config.benchmarks = config_for(:benchmarks)` in the `config/application.rb` file.

I also added the path to `config/spring.rb` yet when I go to the console and enter `Rails.application.config_for(:benchmarks)` it returns an empty hash.

What am I missing here? I'm running Rails 5.2.1.

Comment: Have you restarted the console and spring after changing spring config?

Comment: @mrzasa yes I have

Comment: can you add `config.benchmarks = config_for(:benchmarks)` in `application.rb`

Comment: @7urkm3n I did that as well

Comment: @NickONeill i just tested on mine works clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to touch `config/spring.rb` file. Just make sure you are passing as like in sample below.

```
# config/benchmarks.yml
development:
  test: test

#application.rb
config.benchmarks = config_for(:benchmarks)

#rails console
Rails.application.config_for(:benchmarks)

=> {
     "test" => "test"
   }
```

Comment: What you identified here was my failure to add the `development` key

Comment: @NickONeill Yes :)

Answer (score 1):

config_for wants to have a "section" to pull. That section is the value in Rails.env. If you just have a "flat" .yml which can be valid YML you'll get an empty set.